# Microsoft Azure Powershell error - register-AzureProvider

Tags: powershell, azure

Here is the error with --> `register-AzureProvider`

PS `C:\> register-AzureProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.DevTestLab`

> register-AzureProvider : The term 'register-AzureProvider' is not
>   recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
>   program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
>   verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>   + register-AzureProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.DevTestLab
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (register-AzureProvider:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Should edit question to follow formatting guidelines for the site for code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Azure PowerShell Cmdlets version 0.9.8 (or earlier), you will need to do the following first:

```
Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager
```

Please refer to the documentation on using `Using Azure PowerShell with Azure Resource Manager` here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/powershell-azure-resource-manager/.